# Как сверстать такой блок-подвал?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, нужен подвал как у SpaceX, но не выходит добиться схожести с заданным элементом
https://www.spacex.com/
Вышло пока что так:

```js
#footer{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: rgb(0,0,0,0.9);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    
   
  }
  #footer a{
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
   
  }
  #footer a:hover{
    color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  }
  #footer span{
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <p>
      <span style="color: rgb(233, 233, 233);">BrandLogistics&nbsp&copy;&nbsp2021</span>
      <a href="#" rel="noopener" target="_blank" class="social" >TWITTER</a>
      <a href="#" rel="noopener" target="_blank" class="social">INSTAGRAM</a>
      <a href="#" rel="noopener" target="_blank" class="social">FACEBOOK</a>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.footer {
  background: #000;
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer-item {
  margin: 0 20px;
  font: 12px/24px D-DIN-Bold, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

span.footer-item {
  color: #979797;
}

a.footer-item {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .15s color;
}

a.footer-item:hover {
  color: #8b939b;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <span class="footer-item">BrandLogistics&nbsp&copy;&nbsp2021</span>
    <a href="#" class="footer-item">Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="footer-item">Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="footer-item">Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="footer-item">Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="footer-item">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```